# Why did Paul Vitti meet the Little Caesar TV show director?

Tags: plot-explanation, analyze-that

In **Analyze That**, Paul Vitti hated the Little Caesar TV Show during his prison days.

Then why did Paul Vitti meet the Little Caesar director in person?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Because he's working

Raoul (the producer) asked him...

> Listen, Paul, I have to ask, would you be interested in working on Little Caesar......as a consultant and technical advisor, you know, coaching the actors? Making sure the dialogue rings true.

Vitti hated the show because it wasn't true to life and Ben offers him the opportunity to use his own life experiences on the show to improve it.

Comment: This movie doesn't have IMDB **Synopsis**, Then How you able to able post the answer to my question?

Comment: I read the script.

Comment: You mean [here](http://www.screenplaydb.com)

Comment: A couple of places.

Comment: Do You have facebook ID ?

Comment: Not one I care to share.